# Reuse AngularJS Component in another Module (Dependency Injection)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I reuse a simple angular component via Dependency injection?

**Component:**

```
angular.module("navbar", []).component("nav", function() {
    console.log("component loaded");
});
```

**Other Module Controller I want to use it in:**

```
angular.module('CtrlHome', ['navbar']).controller('HomeController', 
function($rootScope, $scope) {
});
```

**And finally use it in the template**

```
<nav></nav>
```

It throws me a "injector modulerr" error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . modulerr means that loaded module wasn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component isn't defined correctly. The `component` registration method takes a string and an object as input. The object describes the component. So this would be the correct way to register a component with the module:

```
angular.module("navbar", []).component("nav", {
    controller: function(){
        console.log("component loaded");
    }
});
```

There are several other properties you can include to describe a component, i.e. `bindings: {}` and `template: '<div>Hello, World!</div>'`.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle or snippet?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I think you accidently put a squared bracket. i'm still getting the same error though after changing it .

Comment: Yes, good catch. That's a brace :-) If you still get the same error, perhaps your `navbar` module isn't registered with angular before the `CtrlHome` is registered. Try checking they're loaded in the correct order.

Comment: As long as modules are used like angular.module('CtrlHome', ['navbar']), loading order doesn't matter. The error means that the module wasn't loaded at all at bootstrap time.

Comment: That was the essence of what I was trying to say. I may have just explained myself poorly.

Comment: Ups well registering it in the index.html helps alot ... ive worked with webpack for too long ... thanks anyways