# What is the best way to import a component from another module, in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, components

I have 2 sub-modules in my AngularJS (v1.7) app, let's call them A and B. I'm trying to import a component (with html template and controller) from module B (componentB), to be used inside the template of a component in module A (componentA).

After reading [Reuse AngularJS Component in another Module (Dependency Injection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715053/reuse-angularjs-component-in-another-module-dependency-injection), I first tried to do this by specifying componentB as a dependency of componentA and then using it inside componentA's template.

componentA.js

```
angular.module('A', ['componentB']).component('componentA', {...});
```

componentA.html

```
<div>
   <componentB></componentB>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this did not work, even though componentB is correctly defined and being successfully used in module B. I also tried to specify module B as a dependency of module A, by modifying `app.js` as shown below:

```
angular.module('A', ['B'])
.config(...
```

In both cases, I'm getting an

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

I'm having a hard time finding similar questions/articles that relate to AngularJS as opposed to the newer Angular. I'm also pretty rusty with AngularJS so any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward:

```
angular.module("moduleB",[])
.component("componentB", {
     template: "<div>This is Component B from Module B</div>"
});

angular.module("moduleA",["moduleB"])
```

```
<div ng-app="moduleA">
    <component-b></component-b>
</div>
```

The `moduleA` imports components from `moduleB` by declaring `moduleB` as a dependency.

---

### Module Creation vs Retrieval

Only the first module declaration should have dependencies specified.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> angular.module('moduleA', [])
> .controller('ctrl', /* ... */) 
>
> angular.module('moduleA', ['moduleB'])
> .service('serviceA', /* ... */)
> ```

Declaring dependencies again will cause the controller to be unregistered.

### Better

```
angular.module('moduleA', ['moduleB'])

angular.module('moduleA')
.controller('ctrl', /* ... */) 

angular.module('moduleA')
.service('serviceA', /* ... */)
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Module Creation vs Retrieval](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)
- [AngularJS angular.module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

Comment: Thank you! I thought it wasn't working but then found a small typo in the module dependencies. I appreciate the input.